# Error DBD::mysql::db do failed: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'INET_ATON'

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm using [xfilesharing](http://sibsoft.net/xfilesharing_free.html) free without any problems until today when i received these error messages when trying to upload:

> upload.cgi: DBD::mysql::db do failed: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'INET_ATON' at Modules/DataBase.pm line 65.
>
> upload.cgi: Can't exec:s INSERT INTO Files SET file_name=?, file_descr=?, file_code=?, file_del_id=?, file_size=?, file_password=?, file_ip=INET_ATON(?), file_created=NOW()
>
> upload.cgi: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'INET_ATON' at Modules/DataBase.pm line 65.

This is the line 65: `my $rc=$self->{dbh}->do($expr,undef,@_)||die "Can't exec:\s $expr \n".$self->dbh->errstr;`

The full code can be accessed on [pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/RNyXUFNt)

I think the server updated the Perl version and that might be the problem.
Anybody knows how to fix except downgrading Perl?

Comment: You should probably look at the parameter that gets passed to INET_ATON... hard to say what may go on there without more info / code.

Comment: I've added a link to the full file.

Comment: That seems to be only a module. Where is the part where Exec() is called with the INSERT INTO? And a stacktrace would be helpful...

Comment: this is the download link for the xfilesharing http://sibsoft.net/xfilesharing_free.zip

Comment: Did you ask in the Sibsoft support forum?

Comment: I asked them by email, but being a free version I might not get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to error log, this MySQL method ([INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)) expects to have a valid IPv4 address (X.Y.Z.A).

It might be some parameter order problem since such kind of parameter assignment (?) can cause this or the IP address might be a server name or 'localhost' in the config file.

Cheers.

Comment: yes you are right, the problem is with INET_ATON. I removed the function from the query and now it works.